# Get value from a row with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to take the `symbol` of stock and return its `Open` value, but it doesn't even recognize the stock. I am very new to pandas, so I have no idea how to handle this.

```py
def getOpen(symbol):
    try:
        return stock['Open', symbol]
    except:
        pass
    finally:
        return "I couldn't find that stock."
```

data set:

```
Symbol,Open,High,Low,LTP,Chng,% Chng,Volume (lacs),Turnover (crs.),52w H,52w L,365 d % chng,30 d % chng
ADANIPORTS,750,766,713.25,715,-47.45,-6.22,72.2,532.63,901,384.4,79.22,-4.65
ASIANPAINT,"3,101.00","3,167.35","3,091.00","3,138.00",-6.25,-0.2,10.29,322.53,"3,505.00","2,117.15",45.66,5.66
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share a small example of the dataset you are working on to help understand the question better. I'm not sure what are the rows and columns in your data set.

Basics to get around in pandas:

- `df['column_name']` - returns a subset of your data set just with column
- `df.loc['row_index','column_name']` - returns a value from a column and row using column name and row_index

in your case, I think it will be:

- `stock.loc[symbol, 'Open']` - if `Open` is a column and `symbol`s are in rows

or

- `stock.loc['Open', symbol]`- if `symbol`s are in columns and `Open` is a row

Based on the comments, I can see that both `Symbol` and `Open` are columns, try this:

```py
def getOpen(symbol):
try:
    return stock.loc[stock['Symbol'] == symbol,'Open']
except:
    pass
finally:
    return "I couldn't find that stock"
```

Comment: this is the first row of the dataset

Comment: Symbol,Open,High,Low,LTP,Chng,% Chng,Volume (lacs),Turnover (crs.),52w H,52w L,365 d % chng,30 d % chng

ADANIPORTS,750,766,713.25,715,-47.45,-6.22,72.2,532.63,901,384.4,79.22,-4.65
ASIANPAINT,"3,101.00","3,167.35","3,091.00","3,138.00",-6.25,-0.2,10.29,322.53,"3,505.00","2,117.15",45.66,5.66